# Tess4j search for a text in a image at a specific position

Tags: tesseract, tess4j

Hi I would like to know if there is any API method available in tess4j using which I can get text from an image by referring to a specific position

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are need to set `Rectangle` field of `setImage` function

You can read about setImage function in tess4j [documentation](http://tess4j.sourceforge.net/docs/docs-3.4/net/sourceforge/tess4j/Tesseract.html#setImage-int-int-java.nio.ByteBuffer-java.awt.Rectangle-int-). And [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Rectangle.html?is-external=true) about what `Rectangle` is.

Comment: Thanks. I have a screenshot of a bill with random colors in it. I cannot fetch content accurately . What's the ideal way to do this ?. I also tried thresholding it using imagemagick but it dont help. Also tried Greying and Binary conversion method.

Comment: There is no ideal way to do this. Issue you're describing is very hard to solve & isn't solved in general way at the moment. You can try some commercial projects which would do what you need, but their accuracy is also far from perfect. As a starting point you should try to binarize your image so that content isn't lost. After that try to remove everything which is not a text (that's tricky, but you can find ways to do that here on SO).